# Web api for random words

Tags: gratis, open-source, javascript

I am looking for a web api that is open source that will help me generate random words that are actually in the dictionary I have check out wordink but they charge for all requests over 15k an hour. I have also checked out chance.js but that library will spit out random letters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would check out [Random Word API](http://randomword.setgetgo.com/). It's simple and free to use. If your looking for JS code, here it is:

> **Example Usage with Javascript/JQuery**
>
> ```
> function RandomWord() {
>     var requestStr = "http://randomword.setgetgo.com/get.php";
>
>     $.ajax({
>         type: "GET",
>         url: requestStr,
>         dataType: "jsonp",
>         jsonpCallback: 'RandomWordComplete'
>     });
> }
>
> function RandomWordComplete(data) {
>     alert(data.Word);
> }
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but is it possible to write the JQuery in pure javascript

Comment: You could add query to your script or your could fetch it without query, let me see if I can write something quickly to get it

Comment: http://pastebin.com/vjiGaFki

Comment: A great API, thanks. I also liked http://randomimage.setgetgo.com/

Comment: Great:), glad to help

Comment: Referenced API endpoint down at this reading :(

Comment: yeah. I seem to be getting a 404 after the URL I was using http://setgetgo.com/randomword/get.php was saying unavailable